# Configure Python to Complex Django Project

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest

I need to configure pytest in my django application. But the structure of the directories is different of what I'm used to.

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admcore 
│   ├── ...
│   ├── cauth 
│   ├── webservice
│   └── webshell
├── doc
│   └── ...
├── lib 
│   └── ...
├── ...
└── project  
     ├── __init__.py  
     ├── globalsettings.py 
     ├── local
     │   ├── __init__.py  
     │   ├── app.uwsgi 
     │   ├── manage.py 
     │   ├── settings.py  
     │   └── wsgi.py
     ├── mailconf.py 
     └── urls.py
```

I created `pytest.ini`

```py
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=sgp.local.test_settings
addopts = --nomigrations --cov=. --cov-report=html
```

and `test_settings.py` files

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from project import globalsettings

SECRET_KEY = "12341234AFDQFDQSDFAZR123D" 

ROOT_PATH = '/usr/local/sgp'
BASEURL_ROOT = ''

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:'
    }
}
```

And I put the two files in `project` directory.

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admcore 
│   ├── ...
│   ├── cauth 
│   ├── webservice
│   └── webshell
├── doc
│   └── ...
├── lib 
│   └── ...
├── ...
└── project  
     ├── __init__.py  
     ├── globalsettings.py 
     ├── local
     │   ├── __init__.py  
     │   ├── app.uwsgi 
     │   ├── manage.py
     │   ├── pytest.ini
     │   ├── settings.py 
     │   ├── test_settings.py
     │   └── wsgi.py
     ├── mailconf.py 
     └── urls.py
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. I have one test in webservice app, but when I run `pytest` command I got:

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
Django settings: project.local.test_settings (from environment variable)
rootdir: /project/local, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.5.1, cov-2.7.1
collected 0 items


---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.7.4-final-0 -----------
Coverage HTML written to dir htmlcov

=========================================================================================================== no tests ran in 0.15s ============================================================================================================
```

I have no ideia how to configure pytest to this project.

Comment: With this setup, `pytest` will only be able to run tests only from `project/local` (this is what the `rootdir` output also tells you). Move the `pytest.ini` up in the directory structure. Then, if you want `pytest` to discover tests in `apps/webservice`, you will need to change test discovery settings, see [Changing standard (Python) test discovery](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html).

Comment: The only way that works, was put the pytest.ini file in apps/. What you said about pytest will only be able to run tests only from project/local help to try this.

Comment: Now I can't find a way to setup the export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. I put the settins file in project/local/ path, but when I do `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.local.test_settings` I got `ImportError: No module named 'project'`

Comment: Ok, now it's working. I put `pytest.ini` in root directory, I define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.local.test_settings` and run pytest as `PYTHONPATH=. pytest`

Comment: Or you can run `python -m pytest` so you don't need to specify `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: yyeehh thank you! if you want, could you put your explanation as an answer to my question (and not a comment)? so I can finish the topic and choice you answer

Comment: now I'm just trying to use the sqlite database to test, but the original model was made to postgress, and I have some inconsistencies